# How to upgarde my Extjs application from 4 to 6?

Tags: extjs, migration, upgrade

Now in my application i'm using Extjs 4 and i want to migrate it to Extjs 6 to be responsive design . But my application is not created by Sencha CMD then i can not use this tool for upgrading .is it possible to uppgrade by only changing this resources in my HTML views:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ext-all.css"     />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ext-4.1.1a/ext-all.js"  ></script>
```

Comment: I do not think there is an option to migrate just by changing an extjs source file. I would suggest to migrate from 4 to 5 then think about migration from 5 to 6 (which will be much easier)

Comment: yes you are right Mr @Areca, but my problem is that my application doesn't respect the architecture of an Extjs App(ie: application created by Sencha CMD)

Comment: So your app lives in only one js file?

Comment: No what i mean is i'm not using MVC architecture , then i create my stores, models and components directly in my html views

Comment: 4 and 6 are using different architecture, I am suggestion to start a new project. you can let the old one access to the new project or modules by using links

Comment: good idea @aviram83 , but i think that this need a lot of work because i'm using Thymeleaf for template engine  and spring framework

Comment: @Wakrim could you please share your inputs that how you upgrade the version.i am stuck with the same condition..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid using CMD tool and link the full library sources manually, if that's what you are asking. It probably won't work out of the box for an existing Ext4 app if there were some breaking changes:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext/packages/charts/classic/triton/resources/charts-all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext/packages/ux/classic/triton/resources/ux-all.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/classic/theme-triton/theme-triton.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/packages/charts/classic/charts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext/packages/ux/classic/ux.js"></script>
</head>
```