# What are the required folders to start using Ext JS 6?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs6-modern

Ext JS 6 contains `37,903` items that total `504 MB`.

**Here is the content of the package:**

[image]

I need to learn which files (white entries) & folders (blue entries) are **required** in order to use Ext JS 6 **without using Sencha Cmd**.

p.s. I am not using dynamic loading. I always import ext-all.js and theme-X-all.css files which are located under the `build` folder.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36482163/20128

Comment: The package structure is changed with 6; it is not same with the one declared in the answer you linked. @serg

Comment: My answer was for Extjs6, it's the files you need to include if you don't want to use cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha has a great getting started guide located here:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/getting_started/getting_started.html

This assumes you have sencha CMD which is only available if you purchase a license (not GPL version).  With sencha CMD, it automatically extracts the files you need when you run "Sencha App Watch".

If you don't have a commercial license it's best to link to the full sencha library that has everything include in one file.  If you are starting out I recommend you use the debug and commented version so you will see your errors better.  You can find a link to directions to do that here:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/guides/other_resources/extjs_faq.html

(and scroll to "How can I build an application without Sencha Cmd?")

I understand your concern seeing tens of thousands of files.  Sencha ExtJS has a pretty steep learning curve but once you learn it there are big pay backs in productivity.  All those files really help in debugging.  Other libraries just cram them all together and when things don't work you are left without a clue.

HTH's

Comment: CMD doesn't require a commercial license, it's a standalone package you can go and download for free.

Comment: hi @serg I wonder if this is wrong "and Sencha Cmd are only available under a Sencha commercial license and are not available under any open source license."  https://www.sencha.com/legal/open-source-faq/

Comment: Probably their license text is outdated. On their site it just says "download for free" and gives you a direct link to a zip package with CMD

Comment: Thanks **Peter** for brief explanation, actually I have been using Ext JS for a long time. But I always include `extjs-all-debug.js` and the theme css file that contains all rules. As you know the size of whole package of Ext JS increases day by day. The size of whole package of `Ext JS 6` is `504 MB`. I wonder what files are really needed. Can I use whole library with including these two files?

Comment: @talha06  Yes you can is my understanding.  I've done that on small test cases with no issues.  When I'm targeting audiences for highly interactive apps, 500MB is not a problem but clearly a disaster for consumer or general mobile.  Sencha does provide tools (jbuilder) that would let you pick what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you really should try to use Sencha Cmd, it reduces your app size and the number of files significantly.
However, If for some reason you don't want to use it, then it is safe to delete the build folder and the build.xml file.
If you are using ExtJS classic then you should keep the classic folder, otherwise delete it. The same goes for the modern folder.
You can also delete the cmd and examples folder.
You won't need the LICENSE file and the licenses folder, however, you should keep it for legal reasons.
Also, delete the Readme, release-notes, templates, sass and welcome files and folders.

You won't need those if you are not using Sencha Cmd, but then again, I advise you to use it, it does a lot better job at creating a nice and clean build of your app.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, my application is not solely built on Ext JS since I use various JS libraries together for different requirements. Otherwise I am very well aware of the benefits of Sencha Cmd especially when it comes to performance.